# How to get CGFloat value from NSLayoutConstraints?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I am working on screen where I want to make this profile view circular. But I am not getting height or width from `imageView.frame.height` to use it in `layer.cornerRadius`. Please help me. Thanks.

[image]

Here is the code for reference.

```
private func addImageView() {
        topView.addSubview(profilePicView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            profilePicView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.centerXAnchor),
            profilePicView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3)
            ])

        profilePicViewTopAnchor = profilePicView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 64)
        profilePicViewTopAnchor?.isActive = true

        profilePicViewHeightAnchor = profilePicView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.3)
        profilePicViewHeightAnchor?.isActive = true
    }
```

And I am trying to get values as,

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print((profilePicViewHeightAnchor?.constant)!)
        profilePicView.layer.cornerRadius = (profilePicViewHeightAnchor?.constant)! / 2
        profilePicView.clipsToBounds = true

    }
```

***SOLVED***

After everyones help I got this solution which works perfectly fine for me,

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        let radius = redView.frame.height * 0.3
        profilePicView.layer.cornerRadius = radius / 2
        profilePicView.clipsToBounds = true

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    }
```

Thanks to all you guys. Really appreciated the help.

Comment: Are you using Storyboard?

Comment: Have you tried with `imageviewHeightConstraint.constant`?

Comment: Add the relevant code to the question please.

Comment: @iDev750 nope, I am using auto layouts programmatically

Comment: `profilePicViewHeightAnchor.constant` will always be zero. You should be accessing `frame` of the `profilePicView` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as `imageView.frame` and also move those `top` and `height` `anchors` inside the `activate` method and remove class variables(i.e, `profilePicViewTopAnchor` & `profilePicViewHeightAnchor`)

Comment: @Kamran Nope, `profilePicView.frame.height` is not working. Giving me 0.0 and `top` and `heightAnchor` are going to change afterward thats why I am placing them outside.

Comment: @VijayKharage Make sure you access the `frame` after setting the `size`(`width`, `height`) constraints. If the size constraints are not activated you can not get the correct `frame` values. Whenever you are updating constraints, try calling `self.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Comment: Yes I am accessing at right point @Kamran. I am getting `profilePicView.frame.height` as 85.0 while I am dismissing from my viewController but while pushing, it shows height 0.0

Answer (score 6):

This must be because the time you are accessing the `frame` for `imageView`, the layout constraints are not laid out by the `autolayout`. So, If your `imageView` is inside a `UIViewController` class then you should `override` the below method and then access the `width` and `height`.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    print(imageView.frame.height)
}
```

If `imageView` is inside a custom view then you can `override` the below method and then access the `frame`,

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    print(imageView.frame.height)
}
```

Comment: That means you need to set constraints properly for `imageView`. It would be helpful if you can include code or storyboard/xib constraints in your question so that one can provide a better solution.

Comment: Updated my question please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this it helps to you.

```
imageView.layer.cornerRadius =  imageView.frame.size.height / 2
imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Make sure your height and width of imageView is same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set in storyboard on identifier inspector. like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can Also use ViewDidAppear.because at this time Autolayout engine started to layout Constraint.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    super.viewDidAppear()
    print(imageView.frame.height)
}
```

Comment: Did the same but all in vain

Comment: so you don't get height right?.could you please print other component height in viewdidappear

Answer (score -1):

Try this extension:

```
 extension UIView {

        @IBInspectable
        /// Should the corner be as circle
        public var circleCorner: Bool {
            get {
                return min(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width) / 2 == cornerRadius
            }
            set {
                cornerRadius = newValue ? min(bounds.size.height, bounds.size.width) / 2 : cornerRadius
            }
        }
    }
```